# How can I stop water from coming up through the floor?

Tags: basement, floor

I have a house that is on a high water table, and water is coming up through the floor. The property was excavated around the perimeter a couple of years ago and installed a new Big "O". Drycore was then installed. The walls are fine now but the floor issue has not been solved.

Do you know of a product or process that would resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to talk to a professional.

Comment: There is no single product for an easy fix to this. It involves carefully designed drainage systems, possibly sump pumps, waterproofing, grading, etc.